# limit and integral in the Lp space with Schwartz class.

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

Can we actually interchange limit and integral for $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$. Or it's just the limit and integral happen both equal to 0?

An exercise:
Show that we can interchange the limit and integral:
$\lim_{y\rightarrow0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-y)-f(x)|^p dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{y\rightarrow0} |f(x-y)-f(x)|^p dx = 0,$ for $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$.

This an exercise from a book, I showed they separately equal to 0 and therefore forms the equal sign

Comment: Apply MVT and use the fact that $x^{2}f'(x)$ is bounded. Use the dominating function $g(x)=1$ for $|x| <2$ and $\frac 1 {1+(|x|-1)^{2}}$ for $|x| \geq 2$.

Comment: So it is true that we could interchange the limit and integral under Lp space?

Comment: If your assuming continuity of translates in $L^{p}$ then there is nothing to prove since both sides are $0$. But if that theorem has not been proved in the book you will have to use the fact that $f$ is rapidly decreasing.

Comment: I used the rapid decreasing property to show the limit of integral is 0. But I do not see how directly the interchange happens. Could you please elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 0):

For $|y|\le 1$ and $p > 1/(2n)$

$$\sup_x\ (1+x^{2n}) |f(x)-f(x-y)|\le \sup_x \int_{-y}^0 (1+x^{2n})|f'(x+t)|dt $$ $$\le \sup_x \int_{-y}^0 (1+(x+t+1)^{2n}) |f'(x+t)|dt$$ $$ \le \int_{-y}^0 \sup_x (1+(x+t+1)^{2n}) |f'(x+t)|dt = |y| A$$

where $A = \sup_x (1+(x+1)^{2n}) |f'(x)|$ is finite because $f'$ is Schwartz.

Thus

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x-y)-f(x)|^p dx\le \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{A|y|}{(1+x^{2n})^p} dx$$